# makefile: how to show line numbers for debugging?

Tags: makefile

Is there a way to have make display the line number where it declares an error? The `-d` switch doesn't seem to cut it.

**Updated**: Example output:

```
Reaping winning child 0x08aa8648 PID 9381  
/bin/sh: Syntax error: "then" unexpected (expecting "fi")
```

Comment: oh lord, the -d in make is the most useless oververbose thing ever

Comment: ... that's what I am concluding... at least for the time being.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It gives you the line number by default:

```
$ make
Makefile:11: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

If you are redirecting output into the file, do not forget to redirect stderr then.

Ahh, It's not a `make`, but `sh` error.
Try to use `set -x` command to switch the shell in debug mode.

```
[ctpython]$ set -x
++ pwd
++ kill -STOP 7136
[ctpython]$ make
+ make
Makefile:11: *** missing separator.  Stop.
++ pwd
++ kill -STOP 7136
```

Comment: not it doesn't... could it be because I am executing "shell" commands?

Comment: Yeah, it's shell. I've updated my post after you added the output.